# Single Page Application (SPA) not loading on iOS mobile

Tags: ios, angularjs, iphone, single-page-application

Well, I'm not even sure what to tell you or what code to show?

I have a SPA that I developed with AngularJS that includes another SPA as a directive

This SPA works in every browser desktop and mobile accept iOS mobile...it try's to load and then crashes and just shows a blank screen...no errors, no 401's or 404's in the Network trace.

It just abandons loading and shows a blank screen.

Comment: Is there anything in the console (errors in JS)? HTTP errors (4xx) are not the only way a web app can fail.

Comment: It seems like it might be related WAP/Windows Integration and redirects on our servers...